# Adding an .mp3 file to google drive (or any online storage) and playing it

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer, mp3, drive

I have 100 mp3 files i need to add them to google drive (or any drive) and with play them one after other in android app.

1. Is it good idea to put .mp3 to google drive for playing in andorid app, or there are a better places for that ?
2. Can i play music from google drive(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zYZft7FRM-zln1QxsIk661TJVAonhura) with android media player ?

Comment: Why not using something like an S3 bucket?

Comment: Is amazon s3 buchet free ? The size of all mp3's is almost 1gb.

Comment: No it's not free, but it's very cheap.  Especially for something as small as 1 GB.  Actually, you'll probably fall well into the free tier for the first year.